# Как правильно отпавить сформированый json?

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Пытаюсь создать свое расширение. Получается `js` скриптом формирую `json`, а  дальше закидываю в `input type='hidden'` Вот сама форма

```
<form id="formMenu" action="update" method="post">
    <div class="form-group field-menuget-key_setup required">
          <label class="control-label" for="menuget-key_setup">Введите название меню (на английском)</label>
          <input id="menuget-key_setup" class="name" name="MenuGet[key_setup]" value="forHer" aria-required="true" type="text">
</div><div class="form-group field-contentForJson required">
      <input id="contentForJson" class="form-control" name="MenuGet[vaelye]" value="" type="hidden">
</div>
       <a id="secures" class="btn btn-success col-lg-offset-8 col-md-offset-8 col-sm-offset-6" href="#">Сохранить меню</a>
```

вот скрипт js

```
$("#secures").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var menu = {};
        var extra = {};
        $("#menu-to-edit li").each(function (i) {
            if ($(this).data('menu')) {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                var model = $(this).data('model');
                var alias = $(this).data('alias');
                var depth = parseInt($(this).attr('data-depth'));
                var path = $(this).data('path');
                title = $(this).data('title').toString();
                var key = 'menu' + $(this).attr('data-item');
                var addmenu = {
                    title: title,
                    id: id,
                    model: model,
                    alias: alias,
                    depth: depth,
                    path: path,
                    imgPath: imgPath,
                    imgName: imgName
                };
                menu[key] = addmenu;
            }
           $('#contentForJson').val(JSON.stringify(menu, "", 4));
           $('#formMenu').submit();
        });
```

но мне кажется что от этого кода несколько пованивает говно кодом (ну не нравиться мне передавать `json` в `value`, `inputа`). Есть лучшие практики как это сделать ?

Comment: Чтобы запостить и в этом же переходе перейти на страницу наверное это единственный вариант (для небольшого количество данных может можно еще в get и window.location). Тут скорее говно логика - зачем вообще переходить как я понимаю на туже страницу, почему просто аяксом не послать?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev там аякса столько натыкано, что обработчик просто не справится.